# Is passing $this to a static method tight coupling?

Tags: php, loose-coupling

Here is a simple example:

```
class Class_A {   
    protected $_property;

    public function method()
    {
        Class_B::method($this);
    }

    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this->_property;
    }
}

class Class_B {
    public static function method(Class_A $classA)
    {
        $classA->getProperty();
    }
}

$classA = new ClassA();
$classA->method();
```

Is it ever okay to pass *$this* as a parameter to the method of another class? Or is that **always** going to be tight coupling? I could pose another similar example using a Factory Pattern in place of the static method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact behaviour of `Class_A` and `Class_B`, but in general it would probably be better to define an interface which is implemented by `Class_A` and type hint for that. The methods of `Class_A` that are required by `Class_B` (e.g. `getProperty()`) should appear in your interface. Then, if you want to switch `Class_A` with another class at a later date, all it has to do is implement the same interface.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. Now I'm trying to think of the exact behaviour that would make it tightly coupled

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien) for more information. In summary: it's the fact that in your example `Class_B` is dependent on `Class_A`, whereas using an interface removes that dependency. You could independently test `Class_B` by using a mock object that implemented that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yet again, it depends on the behavior of the classes in question, but if there was another `Class_C` for example that also used `Class_B` 's static method you might want to consider having `Class_A` and `Class_C` extend `Class_B`. More information can be found on the php [object inheritance page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).