# Where loose and tight coupling would be used as a real scenario?

Tags: java

I have have been reading this article:
[Difference between loose and tight coupling in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien)

After I read this I am still confused and do not understand it at all. I am a Java beginner.

What is the importance of coupling in Java and why? Where, how and when would it be needed while designing code?

Comment: Try to explain what you understand by coupling yourself and we'll tell you if it's a wrong assumption ;-)

Comment: @Darwind Tight coupling means, more dependency. Multiple classes depends on one another. Loose coupling means, less dependency so classes does not need to depend on one another. I am sorry, If I have told you anything wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Tight Coupling

- In complex cases the logic of one class will call the logic of another class just to provide the same service
- If this happen there is the so called tight-coupling between the two classes.
- In this case the first class that wants to call the logic from the second class will have to create an object from the second class

**Example:** we have two classes first is `traveller` and the second is a `car`. `Traveller` class is calling logic of `car` class; in this case traveller class creates an object of car class.

**This will mean the `car` class will depend on the `traveller` object.**

```
Public class Traveller {
    Car c = new Car();
    Public void startJourney() {
        c.move();
    }
}

Public class Car {
    Public void move(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Here `traveller` object is *tightly coupled* with `car` object.
If `traveller` wants to change from `car` to `plane` then the whole `traveller` class has to be changed like the following:

```
Public class Traveller {
    Plane p = new Plane();
    Public void startJourney() {
        p.move();
    }
}

Public class Plane {
    Public void move(){
        ...
    }
}
```

### Loose Coupling

- Our main object, `traveller` in this case will allow an external entity, a so called `container` to provide the `object`. So `traveller` doesn't have to create an own class from the `car` or `plane` object it will get it from the `container`
- When a object allow dependency injection mechanism.
- The external entity, the `container` can inject the `car` or `plane` object based on a certain logic, a requirement of the `traveller`.

**Example:**

```
Public class Traveller {
    Vehicle v;

    Public void setV(Vehicle v) {
        this.V = V;
    }
    Public void startJourney() {
        V.move();
    }
}
```

Here `traveller` class injects either a `car` or a `plane` object. No changes required in `traveller` class if we would like to change the dependency from car to a plane.

`Traveller` class took a vehicle reference, so an external object (Container) can inject either `car` object or `plane` object, depends on requirement of `traveller`.

Comment: "This will mean the car class will depend on the traveller object". I don't think this is correct. It is the traveller object that is dependent on the car. A very nice example though.

Answer (score 8):

**Tight-Coupling:-**

1. While creating complex application in java, the logic of one class will call the logic of another class to provide same service to the clients.
2. If one class calling another class logic then it is called collaboration.
3. When one class is collaborating with another class then there exists tight-coupling between the two classes.
4. If one class wants to call the logic of a second class then they first class need an object of second class it means the first class create an object of second class.
5. For example, if we have two classes called traveller and car, traveller class is calling logic of car class; in this case traveller class creates an object of car class.
6. In the above traveller class and car classes, car class object of dependency for traveller object.

**Example:-**

**[image: Traveller]**      [image]

- In the above example traveller object is tightly coupled with car
  object because in place car object  if you want to use bike object
  then, we need to make changes in Traveller class

**Example :-**

[image: travellor 1]  [image: car1]

**Loose-Coupling:-**

1. In Loose-Coupling, when one object is depending on another class object, some external entity will provide that dependency object to the main object that external object we call as a Container.
2. In order to get loose-coupling between objects the following two rules are required
3. The classes should follow POJI/POJO model.
4. Apply dependency injection mechanism.

**For example:-**

[image: interface]

[image: travellor 2]

- In the above traveler class, an external entity injects either car
  (or) Bike object.
- In traveler, these are no changes required we are shifting the
  dependency from car to a Bike.
- In the above traveler class, we are token vehicle reference, so that
  an external object (Container) can injects either car object    (or)
  Bike object, depends on requirement if a traveler.
- In spring frame work, spring container follows dependency injection
  mechanism and injects the dependency objects required for a    main
  object.
- Spring frame work is much success because of one of the main reason
  is it promotes Loose-Coupling between the objects.

**Source:-**  [Tight-coupling and Loose-coupling between objects](http://javaeasy.weebly.com/types-of-coupling.html)