# UML Is it possible to use Aggregation and Composition with two classes?

Tags: java, associations, uml, class-diagram

I have just began learning UML, and I was wondering if a class could composite one way and aggregate the other way (if you understand what I mean). Let's make an example:

[image: My example]

Maingui.java:

```
private controller;

public Maingui() {   
  controller = new Controller(this); 
}
```

Controller.java

```
private maingui;

public Controller(Maingui gui) {
  maingui = gui;
  doSomethingWithMainGui();
}

private void doSomethingWithMainGui() {
  maingui.doSomeThing();
}
```

Is this the correct way to show the association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct way to show assocation, but it's example of bad style app architecture. One of principles of good style architecture is loose coupling. You can read here about it: [What is the difference between loose coupling and tight coupling in the object oriented paradigm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien)

Comment: I'm seeing a logical disconnect here, but then I fell on my head as a child.  How can two objects each be aggregates of each other, let alone composed of each other?