# Why tighly coupled code is hard to unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tightly-coupled-code

I have heard that tighly coupled code is hard to unit test. I dont understand how? Can somebody explain with example.

Comment: @StefanBeike Basically unlayered code with direct dependencies between implementing classes, no interfaces or other mechanisms such as events or message passing that would provide with loosely coupled code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tight coupling means that you use implementations instead of interfaces, reducing the array of options when it comes to creating mock implementations and other testing utilities. It may helped by using mocking frameworks (like Mockito for Android) but should nonetheless be avoided, as it is a bad practice.

However, this is probably the least problematic aspect of highly coupled code. It is generally discouraged, because it limits refactoring and/or expanding possibilities. You should always keep some level of abstraction in your code, to be able to easily implement new modules and change current implementations. But do not overdo it, because programs which have lots on interface-implementation exclusive pairs are very redundant and hard to debug.

In general, you should have a look at some open-source projects and see how those are tested (for Android, check out the Google I/O app for example) and how the testing approach is reflected in the code. It all comes with experience and there is no better way to learn it than by analyzing how pros do it :-)