# How to update a complex type (model) property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encapsulation

I have two models, `Ship` and `Sector`, where `Ship` has a property named `Location` which is an instance of the `Sector` class, and `Destination` which is another instance of the `Sector` class. Considering encapsulation the ship itself should be responsible for updating these properties, so I made a `Move()` method that calculates how much progression the ship made and should update the `Location` property accordingly. If the new location is different from the destination (there are sectors in between and the ship is halfway), how do I get a reference to the instance of that `Sector`?

```
public class Ship
{
   public Sector Location { get; set; }
   public Sector Destination { get; set; }

   public void Move() 
   {
   // some magic happens here. Now I would like to update the Location.
   }
}
```

I use Entity Framework and a repository pattern. So I have a `SectorRepository` and a `ShipRepository` that both implement the following interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
   T Get(int id);
   T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
   void Add(T entity);
   void Remove(T entity);
   List<T> GetAll();
   List<T> Search(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);      
}
```

I could make an instance of `SectorRepository` in the Ship model, but that feels like [Tight Coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/), which I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Ship.Move()` needs to load sectors in order to record it's new position, then it would be perfectly fine to pass an implementation of the `ISectorRepository` interface (or an "`ISectorFinderService`") as a parameter to the `Move()` method. The key is to realise A) that interface is part of your domain model, so this doesn't violate any layers, and B) by your implementation, `Ship` is already tightly coupled to the concept of sectors, so passing an `ISectorFinderService` (with a suitable level of abstraction) doesn't really add any new conceptual dependencies.

However, I have no idea what your sectors really represent, or how the move algorithm works. Perhaps you should have a method `Sector.GetNextSector(direction)`?

Comment: I needed to make some minor changes in my architecture but eventually chose the passing of the `ISectorRepository` to the `Move()` method as the best approach. I have considered your second suggestion but found it more complex in my situation. Sectors are organised in a grid but the SectorIDs are semi-random. A Sector is created when needed so Sector 12 is not necessarily next to Sector 11, etc. Thank you for your suggestions!