# How to select the right architectural/design patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architectural-patterns

I am doing my own research project, and I am quite struggling regarding the right choice of architectural/design patterns.

In this project, after the "system" start, I need to do something in background (tasks, processing, display data and so on) and at the same be able to interact with the system using, for example, keyboard and send some commands, like "give me status of this particular object" or "what is the data in this object".

So my question is - what software architectural/design patterns can be applied to this particular project? How the interraction between classes/objects should be organized? How should the objects be created?

Can, for example, "event-driven architecture" or "Microkernel" be applied here? Some references to useful resources will be very much appreciated!
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Core functionality sound like  [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). In any case it seems like you have some complex app, so it is better draw you app design on paper (or some UML tool) first, this should be a combination of many patterns.

Comment: Gut feeling and experience. The subject is too broad.

Comment: Check this book [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

Comment: Careful with design patterns. If you sprinkle them throughout your code hoping that everything will work great, you'll soon have an unreadable, boilerplate full mess. They are recipes, not solutions. My advice to you is pick a piece of paper and a pencil and start drawing all the entities of your domain, with all their requisites, and see how they relate. Strive for high cohesion and loose coupling. Leave the design patterns for the implementation stage.

Comment: @rcosteira Excellent advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful with design patterns. If you sprinkle them throughout your code hoping that everything will work great, you'll soon have an unreadable, boilerplate full mess. They are recipes, not solutions.

My advice to you is pick a piece of paper and a pencil and start drawing all the entities of your domain, with all their requisites, and see how they relate. If you want to get somewhat serious about it, you can do something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

When defining your entities, strive for **high cohesion** and **loose coupling**.

High cohesion means that you should keep similar functionalities together. In a very simple example, if you have a class that reads stuff from a file and processes it, the class has low cohesion, since reading and processing are two very distinct functionalities. In this case, you would want a class for each functionality.

As for loose coupling, it means that your entities should be independent of each other. Using the example above, supposed that you are now the proud owner of two highly cohesive classes - one that reads stuff from a file (Reader), and one that processes that stuff (Processor). Now, suppose that the Processor class has an instance of the Reader class, and calls it in order to get its input. In this case, we can say that both classes are tightly coupled, since Processor won't work without Reader. In the OOP world, the solution for this is typically the use of interfaces. You can find a neat example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832047/2333010).

After defining an initial model of your domain and gathering as much knowledge about it as you can, you can now start to think about the implementation's architecture. This is were you can start thinking about the architectural patterns. Event driven architecture, clean architecture, MVP, MVVM... It will all depend on your domain. It is your job to know which pattern will fit best. Spoiler alert: this can be extremely hard to do correctly even for experienced engineers, so don't be afraid to fail.

Finally, leave the design patterns for the implementation stage. Their use completely depends on your implementation problems and decisions. Also, DON'T FORCE THEM. Ideally, you will solve a problem and, IF APPLICABLE, you'll see a pattern emerging. Trust me, the last thing you want is to have a case of [design patternitis](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/94/). Anyway, if you need literature on patterns, I totally recommend [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do). It's great no matter your level as an engineer.

Further reading:

- [SOLID principles](https://hackernoon.com/solid-principles-made-easy-67b1246bcdf)
- [Onion Architecture](https://dev.to/remojansen/implementing-the-onion-architecture-in-nodejs-with-typescript-and-inversifyjs-10ad)
- [Clean architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Beautiful answer! See, I asked this question because I have experience in "implementing" complex software systems, when the design is already done and all you have to do is coding, however, I don't have much experience in "designing" of complex software systems, and it is indeed a very complicated task. Thank you very much for the answer, and I mark your answer as accepted.
And a thank you all for all the other answers too, great community!

Answer (score 1):

You have a background task, and it can be used for a message pump/event queue indeed. Then your foreground task would send requests to this background thread and asynchronously wait for the result.

Have a look at the book "Patterns for Parallel Programming".

Answer (score 0):

It is much better if you check a book for Design Patterns. [I really like this one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do).

For example, if you need to get some data from a particular object, you may need the Observer Pattern to work for you and as soon as the object has the data, you (or another object) get to know this data and can work with it, with another pattern (strategy might work, it really depends on what you have to do).

If you have to do some things at the same time, check also the Singleton pattern (well, check the most important ones!).